# Does restlet support ContainerResponseFilter on GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

Reslet 2.2.1 for GAE does not include ContainerResponseFilter (or more generally javax.ws.rs.container.*).

How do I implement such a filter in this environment?

Or is there another work-around to add access-control headers (can be a temporary kludge)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restlet Framework only supports JAX-RS 1.1 spec at this point, an upgrade is planned for RF V2.3 to JAX-RS 2.0 but isn't available or certain at this point.

I would recommend working around this class if possible, or try using Jersey or RESTeasy maybe.

UPDATE: as a workaround, you can manually set the response (CORS) headers by using an org.restlet.routing.Filter subclass that would achieve the same effects by overloading its afterHandle() method.

Comment: Thank you. One of my goals is to retain portability by using standards. Restlet worked out of the box with app engine using the jaxrs and json extensions. The framework works great. Add my vote for jax-rs 2.0. In the meantime, I will overload Filter.